# socket.io request 404 on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, socket.io

My app work locally but when i deploy to heroku the requests to myapp.herokuapp.com/socket.io get a 404 response.

Here's my code :

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var app = express();
var port = 8080;

// Configuration of the server 
require('./ServerConfig').serverConfig(app, express);


var server = http.createServer(app).listen(port)
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
   socket.on('message', function(msg){
    console.log(msg);
    io.emit('message', msg);
  });
});
```

I have just started using nodejs and i dont really understand why it crashes.

Could someone either explain the cause of this bug or how to debug this ?

Thanks !

Comment: Try myapp.herokuapp.com:8080/socket.io

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace line 4 with:

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
```

On Heroku you should bind to the PORT environment variable. See:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/runtime-principles#web-servers